# Arduino and Android ADB

Tags: android, connection, arduino, adb

I am trying to send a message from Arduino to Android, and I am trying this code:

```
byte msg[2];
msg[0] = 2;
msg[1] = 1;
connection->write(2, (uint8_t*)&msg);
ADB::poll();
```

If I run it **one time**, nothing hapends, but if I run it in a loop for 5000 times, it is working. How is that?

---

If I use it with a button, like the following it working to, but how do I use without the button?

```
byte b;
byte msg[2];

b = digitalRead(BUTTON_UP);
if (b != b1) {
    msg[0] = BUTTON_UP;
    msg[1] = b ? 0 : 1;
    Serial.println(msg[0],DEC);
    connection->write(2, (uint8_t*)&msg);
    b1 = b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so here is how it should be done

```
void sendToandroid(int pin, int OnOff){
long lastTime= millis();
byte msg[2];
int x=0;
while(x == 0){
if ((millis() - lastTime) > 500)
  {
      msg[0] = pin;
      msg[1] = OnOff;
      Serial.print(msg[0]);
      Serial.println(msg[1]);
    connection->write(2, (uint8_t*)&msg);
    x=1;
  }
  ADB::poll();
}

}
```